# ConTeXt: hyperlinks with special characters

Tags: context

I need to link to some online resources in my PDF file. Based on [the official documentation](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/url), I have written:

```
\useURL[dbdk] [http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Dark_Knight_(film)] [] [it's link to DBPedia]

Lorem ipsum \goto{the LinkedMDB.org entry on The Dark Knight}[url(http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/6224)], and \from[dbdk] dolor sit amet.
```

Note my code for the link to DBpedia: I had to write it in this convoluted way, instead of using my preferred `\goto`, because the link has the special characters, `(` and `)`. These characters interfered with `url()`. I can't use [HTML's URL encoding scheme](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) because the `%`s interfere with TeX. Is there another escape code format in ConTeXt for use within `\goto{...}[url(...)]`?

---

Addendum:

Using the suggestion by @phg, I tried the following:

```
\startasciimode

Lorem ipsum \goto{the LinkedMDB.org entry on The Dark Knight}[url(http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/6224)], and \goto{it's link to DBPedia}[url(http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Dark_Knight_%28film%29)] dolor sit amet.

\stopasciimode
```

I still had to use escape codes, `%28` and `%29`, to keep it from interfering with `url()`. It turns out that DBpedia does not like these codes, and requires the actual characters. Is there another way I put them in `\goto{...}[url(...)]`?

Comment: Did you try defining your URLs inside a ``\startasciimode ... \stopasciimode`` environment?

Comment: @phg I had not heard of `\startasciimode`. I tried it out just now. Your solution would work on a website like wikipedia, but not on dbpedia.

Comment: Just for my own information (I keep landing on this page when I have a related problem), a percent sign in a url can be accomplished with `\letterpercent` (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/492)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this problem seems to be fixed.  At least for me in TL2017 `\goto{it's link to DBPedia}[url(http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Dark_Knight_(film))]` works as expected.